# On click expanding of rows of a data table in shiny application is not working, How to solve this

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

I have written a code to create a data table in shiny R which when I click the row of interest it should expand and show me the child rows.
However this is working only for the last row of my data table. In the previous rows only the headers of the child table is being shown and not the data.

My data table :
[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwXGA.png)

My output: [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2QS0.png)

`callback = JS("table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});`

```
// Format cars object into another table
var format = function (d) {
    if (d != null) {
        var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] +
            '\">').replace('.', '_') + '<thead><tr>'
        for (var col in d[4][0]) {
            result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
        }
        result += '</tr></thead></table>'
        return result
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

var format_datatable = function (d) {
    var dataset = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= d[4].length - 1; i++) {
        var datarow = $.map(d[4][i], function (value, index) {
            return [value];
        });
        dataset.push(datarow)
    }
    var subtable = $(('table#child_' + d[2] + '_' +
        d[3]).replace('.', '_')).DataTable({
        'data': dataset,
        'autoWidth': true,
        'deferRender': true,
        'info': false,
        'lengthChange': false,
        'ordering': true,
        'paging': false,
        'scrollX': false,
        'scrollY': false,
        'searching': false
    });
};

table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var td = $(this),
        row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        td.html('&oplus;');
    } else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        td.html('&CircleMinus;');
        format_datatable(row.data())
    }
});
")
```

Comment: Can you provide the dataframe ? It's easier to help with a reproducible code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the presence of white spaces in the column `Description` (try to expand row 3, it should work because there's no white space). Thus the JS code generates ids of the child tables with white spaces, and these ids are not valid. In the code below, the white spaces are replaced by `_`, and it works. Moreover, replacing the dots (because an id with dots is not valid) by doing `replace('.', '_')` is not the way to go, because this replaces only the first occurence of a dot. You have to use a global replacement: `replace(/\./g, '_')`. I also do a global replacement for the white spaces: `replace(/\s/g, '_')`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ' ' = rep('&oplus;',2),
  Sr = c(1, 2),
  Description = c("A - B", "X - Y"),
  Details = I(list(list(list(Chromosome = "chr18", SNP = "rs2")), 
                   list(list(Chromosome = "chr19", SNP = "rs3"),
                        list(Chromosome = "chr20", SNP = "rs4")))), 
  check.names = FALSE
)

callback = JS(
  "table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "// Format the nested table into another table",
  "var format = function (d) {",
  "  if (d != null) {",
  "    var result = ('<table class=\"display compact\" id=\"child_' + ",
  "                 ((d[2] + '_' + d[3]).replace(/\\s/g, '_')) +",
  "                 '\">').replace(/\\./g, '_') + '<thead><tr>';", 
  "    for (var col in d[4][0]) {",
  "      result += '<th>' + col + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    result += '</tr></thead></table>';",
  "    return result;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "var format_datatable = function (d) {",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  for (i = 0; i < d[4].length; i++) {",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[4][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var subtable = $(('table#child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3])",
  "                   .replace(/\\./g, '_').replace(/\\s/g, '_')).DataTable({",
  "                     'data': dataset,",
  "                     'autoWidth': true,",
  "                     'deferRender': true,",
  "                     'info': false,",
  "                     'lengthChange': false,",
  "                     'ordering': true,",
  "                     'paging': false,",
  "                     'scrollX': false,",
  "                     'scrollY': false,",
  "                     'searching': false,",
  "                     'sortClasses': false,",
  "                     'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "                   });",
  "};",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {",
  "  var td = $(this),",
  "      row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));",
  "  if (row.child.isShown()) {",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    row.child(format(row.data())).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data())",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(dat, callback = callback, escape = FALSE,
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = 4),
              list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
            )
          ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `table` variable use jQuery selector of the table in the event.

```
$('.table').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var td = $(this),
        row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        td.html('&oplus;');
    } else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        td.html('&CircleMinus;');
        format_datatable(row.data())
    }
});
```

This should work

Documantation: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working. Now the expansion of any row isn't taking place. Also I think the problem is more to do with the format_datatable function.